# CollectionView stop scrolling after user passes bounds

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that contains 50 items, which are just photos. Know I want to know when the user finger passes the collection view bounds and stop scrolling the collection view. Cause right now it will continue to scroll after I pass the bounds of the collection view. How would I be able to achieve this? Would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just deactivate bounce on scroll.

[image: Bounce on scroll]

yourCollectionView.bounces = false

**Docs:**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces